# 500 Server Error when starting local server with MAMP

Tags: php, bitbucket, prestashop, mamp, plesk

i have this problem for some time now.

I made a host called "pro-takuma" with MAMP, database imported from a dump export from plesk and project from bitbucket created with prestashop.

When I open the local server it takes me to a "500 Server Error", not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My .htaccess file:

```
# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
```

My autoload.php file:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

define('_PS_VERSION_', AppKernel::VERSION);

require_once _PS_CONFIG_DIR_.'alias.php';
require_once _PS_CLASS_DIR_.'PrestaShopAutoload.php';
spl_autoload_register(array(PrestaShopAutoload::getInstance(), 'load'));
```

my parameters.php file:

```
<?php return array (

  'parameters' =>

  array (

    'database_host' => 'localhost',

    'database_port' => '',

    'database_name' => 'pro_takuma',

    'database_user' => 'root',

    'database_password' => '',

    'database_prefix' => 'tkm_',

    'database_engine' => 'InnoDB',

    'mailer_transport' => 'smtp',

    'mailer_host' => '127.0.0.1',

    'mailer_user' => NULL,

    'mailer_password' => NULL,

   ...
  ),

);
```

my MAMP php log file

```
[22-Aug-2023 10:25:09 Europe/Madrid] PHP Warning:  require_once(/Users/marketingtakuma/Documents/Takuma/PProjects/PProjects (Synced BB)/takuma-produ-BB/config/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/marketingtakuma/Documents/Takuma/PProjects/PProjects (Synced BB)/takuma-produ-BB/config/autoload.php on line 26
[22-Aug-2023 10:25:09 Europe/Madrid] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/Users/marketingtakuma/Documents/Takuma/PProjects/PProjects (Synced BB)/takuma-produ-BB/config/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.34/lib/php') in /Users/marketingtakuma/Documents/Takuma/PProjects/PProjects (Synced BB)/takuma-produ-BB/config/autoload.php on line 26
```